# How do I only print the links that contain certain text in the description on that page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Im trying to open the links that contain certain words on that page. And if the words are present on that page such as "engineering" then return the link if not pass.

here is what I have so far: The inputs I put are engineering and location is north york

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
import time

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)
base_url = 'https://ca.indeed.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
rcontent = r.content
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "html.parser")

filter_words = ['chemical engineering', 'instrumentation', 'QA']
all_job_url = []
filtered_job_links = []
http_flinks = []
flinks = []

def get_all_joblinks():  # obtains all the links on the search page
    for tag in prettify.find_all('a', {'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"}):
        link = tag['href']
        all_job_url.append(link)

def filter_links():

    for eachurl in all_job_url: # iterates through each link
        rurl = requests.get(base_url + eachurl)
        content = rurl.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        summary = soup.get_text()

        #supposed to filter links based on certain words within text on link page
        if any(word in summary for word in filter_words):
            for filtered_link in soup.find_all('link', {'rel':'canonical'}):
                flink = filtered_link['href'] # obtains only filtered links
                if "http:" in flink:
                    http_flinks.append(flink)
                    print(http_flinks)
                else:
                    flinks.append(flink)
                    #website = webbrowser.open_new(base_url + flink)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print(flinks)
        else:
            print("nothing")
            pass


def search_job():

    while True:

        if prettify.select('div.no_results'):
            print("no job matches found")
            break
        else:
            # opens the web page of job search if entries are found
            website = webbrowser.open_new(url)
            break

get_all_joblinks()
filter_links()
```

Comment: Change this: `"engineering" in summary == True` to: `"engineering" in summary`

Comment: @t.m.adam nvm mind it works!!! great thanks so much

Comment: @t.m.adam sorry I have another question, it might be right in front of me but how would I add multiple strings if I would want to filter it using say 4-10 words?

Comment: If `words` is a list of words to filter, use : `any(word in summary for word in words)` . This evaluates true if `summary` contains any string in `words` . If you want to check if `summary` contains all items in `words` use `all()` instead.

Comment: @t.m.adam great! that worked perfectly

Comment: @t.m.adam actually I just realized that it does not filter the text. As long as there is a searchable job it will obtain the link regardless of filter word. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you show the updated code and an example input for `jobsearch` , `location`  so i can take a look ?

Comment: @t.m.adam I updated the code, the job type input i tried is engineering and location is north york. But even when I put cashier as job it still returns links.

Comment: Sorry but i can't reproduce your results. Using your code as it is i got 1 link for "engineering", "north york" ( because it contains "instrumentation" in `summary` ) , and 0 links for "cashier", "north york". Your filter seems to be working fine, unless you want a negative match ( use `not any()` ) or you expect it to match all words ( use `all()` ) .